# Looking for performance improvements for this query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

This query is taking a long time to execute. We are expecting results in 0 sec, if possible.

Please help me to do any other following:

- Rewrite the query
- Suggest any indexes
- Any other optimization that may be needed.

Also, please help isolate root cause.

Here is the Query And Explain Plan:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM (`xgen_studentMLs`)
    LEFT JOIN `xgen_quizzes`
         ON xgen_studentMLs.quizid = xgen_quizzes.idnum
    WHERE
          `student` = 27126
      AND xgen_studentMLs.topic = 1829
      AND xgen_studentMLs.metatype = 'topic'
      AND (xgen_studentMLs.department='Nursing' OR xgen_studentMLs.department='Biology')
      AND (xgen_quizzes.book IS NULL OR xgen_quizzes.book=0)
    ORDER BY xgen_studentMLs.timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;

+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | xgen_studentMLs | range  | student,mult  | mult    | 265     | NULL                         |   18 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | xgen_quizzes    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | prepu.xgen_studentMLs.quizid |    1 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Here are table structures:

```
mysql> show create table xgen_quizzes\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: xgen_quizzes
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `xgen_quizzes` (
  `idnum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestarted` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `timefinished` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `questionlist` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `topics` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `totalnum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completednum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `assignment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `book` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cqs` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `metatype` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'topic',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnum`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `assignment` (`assignment`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13547573 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table xgen_studentMLs\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: xgen_studentMLs
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `xgen_studentMLs` (
  `student` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ML` float NOT NULL,
  `MI` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `metatype` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'topic',
  `quizid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `student` (`student`),
  KEY `mult` (`topic`,`department`,`student`,`timestamp`,`ML`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: A result returned in 0 (zero) seconds is impossible. That means that the database didn't do anything.

Comment: This is going to need some complex indexes but why haven't you at least added an index on `studentMLs (quizid)` that you use for joining? And shouldn't there be a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on that column, to reference `quizzes (idnum)`?

Comment: And why the 2nd table doesn't have a primary key?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query refactored

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `xgen_studentMLs`
WHERE student = 27126 AND topic = 1829 AND metatype = 'topic'
AND department IN ('Nursing','Biology')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 100) A
LEFT JOIN xgen_quizzes Q ON A.quizid = Q.idnum
WHERE IFNULL(Q.book,0) = 0;
```

The subquery is meant to retrieve only 100 rows before doing the `LEFT JOIN`. You will need an index to assist the subquery

```
ALTER TABLE xgen_studentMLs ADD INDEX new_ndx (student,metatype,topic,department);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Is `IFNULL(Q.book,0) = 0` more efficient than `(Q.book IS NULL OR Q.book=0)`? Oh sorry, your idea is to limit first to 100 rows, so this won't matter much.

Comment: @ypercube If Q.book is NULL, then Q.book=0 should not be evaluted. Perhaps IFNULL performs the same way. The docs say that it uses `IF THEN ELSE` construct ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull ). I would have to look at the source to verify that.  I suppose calling a function requires a tiny bit of overhead when evaluating the query per row versus a direct `IF THEN ELSE` might make it nominally slower. One would have to benchmark that.